# react-native metro bundler error: bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

I am getting the an error when I am using `react-native start`, the bundler error is:

```
bundling failed: ReferenceError: SHA-1 for file /home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js (/home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/lib/polyfills/require.js) is not computed
    at DependencyGraph.getSha1 (/home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:258:13)
    at /home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:211:26
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:46:24)
    at _next (/home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:66:9)
    at /home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:71:7
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:63:12
    at Transformer.transformFile (/home/suvodip/.nvm/versions/node/v8.17.0/lib/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Transformer.js:236:7)
```

I am getting this error ever since I have installed the `react-native-camera`, I don't know if that is the real issue. I have tried doing `rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn install && react-native start -- --reset-cache` but it didn't work. Here is my top level `build.gradle` file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
 ....

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Here is my `app level build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

....
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2"  // Firebase analytics
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    .....
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: "com.google.gms.google-services"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved by `npm uninstall react-native-cli && yarn add global react-native-cli` and I removed all node_modules and reinstalled with `rm -rf node_modules && yarn install`, then it worked.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Works like a charm at MacOS Catalina environment - Android platform.